# How to handle onChange event that sets the state in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am learning React and in the below code I get `...cannot update during an existing state transition...`.  While looking to fix it, I read in SO that setState should not be used within render() as it calls render() repeatedly resulting in infinite loop.  But I dont know how to fix it.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export default class CheckBox extends React.Component{
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {isChecked: false};
    }
    handleChecked () {
        this.setState({isChecked: !this.state.isChecked});
    }
    render(){
        var txt;
        if (this.state.isChecked) {
            txt = 'checked'
        } else {
            txt = 'unchecked'
        }
        return(
          <div>
            <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.handleChecked()}/>
            <p>This box is {txt}</p>
          </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<CheckBox/>, document.getElementById('hello'));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should pass to `onChange` reference to function but not call it., in your example you are calling `handleChecked`(because there is `()` after function) and result pass to `onChange` however result in this case will be `undefined` so `onChange` looks like `onChange={ undefined }`. Also, you can't set state during the initial render, but you are trying to do it with `this.handleChecked()` which contains `this.setState`.

```
export default class CheckBox extends React.Component{
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {isChecked: false};

    // set this (with .bind), 
    // because you need get methods from CheckBox, like .setState
    this.handleChecked = this.handleChecked.bind(this); 
  }

  handleChecked () {
    this.setState({isChecked: !this.state.isChecked});
  }

  render(){
    var txt;
    if (this.state.isChecked) {
      txt = 'checked'
    } else {
      txt = 'unchecked'
    }

    // remove () after handleChecked because you need pass 
    // reference to function
    // also add return statement before <div>
    return <div>
       <input type="checkbox" onChange={ this.handleChecked }/>
       <p>This box is {txt}</p>
    </div>
  }
}
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/131856/)